# Como criar arquivo com data em iso string no nome?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Estou tendo dificuldade para criar um arquivo com o seguinte modelo:

```
2017-01-17T09:42:15.3419026-02:00_teste.txt
```

Quando eu executo o aplicativo para criar aparece esta mensagem:

Não há suporte para o formato do caminho dado.

```
var dataHora = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o");

dataHora.Replace(':', '-');
dataHora.Replace('/', '-');

File.WriteAllText(caminho + dataHora + "_teste.txt");
```

Como eu faço para criar assim?

Comment: Você poderia informar o resultado que aparece dessa concatenação caminho + dataHora + "_teste.txt"

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Use a própria referência para alterar o resultado, na forma usada o resultado do `Replace`()` naõ está sendo usado em lugar algum, nem guardado, a mudança é perdida. Ao contrário do que deve estar imaginando, o método não altera o objeto, ele gera um novo, faça assim:

```
var dataHora = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o").Replace(':', '-').Replace('/', '-');
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0cRT8J). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OliuDS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ChainnedReplace.cs).

Essa forma é um pouco ineficiente, mas não deve ser problema na maioria dos casos.